# Frequency of Characters in Strings as columns in data frame using R

Tags: r

I have a data frame `initial` of the following format

```
> head(initial)
      Strings
1     A,A,B,C
2       A,B,C
3 A,A,A,A,A,B
4     A,A,B,C
5       A,B,C
6 A,A,A,A,A,B
```

and the data frame I want is `final`

```
    > head(final)
      Strings A B C
1     A,A,B,C 2 1 1
2       A,B,C 1 1 1
3 A,A,A,A,A,B 5 1 0
4     A,A,B,C 2 1 1
5       A,B,C 1 1 1
6 A,A,A,A,A,B 5 1 0
```

to generate the data frames the following codes can be used to keep the number of rows high

```
initial<-data.frame(Strings=rep(c("A,A,B,C","A,B,C","A,A,A,A,A,B"),100))
final<-data.frame(Strings=rep(c("A,A,B,C","A,B,C","A,A,A,A,A,B"),100),A=rep(c(2,1,5),100),B=rep(c(1,1,1),100),C=rep(c(1,1,0),100))
```

What is the fastest way I can achieve this? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't row 3 and 6 be `A = 5` (instead of 1) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `base R` methods for this task.  We split the 'Strings' column (`strsplit(...)`), set the names of the output `list` with the sequence of rows, `stack` to convert to `data.frame` with key/value columns, get the frequency with `table`, convert to 'data.frame' and `cbind` with the original dataset.

```
 cbind(df1, as.data.frame.matrix(
                  table(
                    stack(
                     setNames(
                       strsplit(as.character(df1$Strings),','), 1:nrow(df1))
                           )[2:1])))
 #          Strings A B C D
 #1         A,B,C,D 1 1 1 1
 #2     A,B,B,D,D,D 1 2 0 3
 #3 A,A,A,A,B,C,D,D 4 1 1 2
```

or we can use `mtabulate` after splitting the column.

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1, mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df1$Strings), ',')))
#          Strings A B C D
#1         A,B,C,D 1 1 1 1
#2     A,B,B,D,D,D 1 2 0 3
#3 A,A,A,A,B,C,D,D 4 1 1 2
```

#### Update

For the new dataset 'initial', the second method works.  If we need to use the first method with the correct order, convert to `factor` class with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements of 'ind'.

```
df1 <- stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(initial$Strings), ','),
          seq_len(nrow(initial))))
df1$ind <- factor(df1$ind, levels=unique(df1$ind))
cbind(initial, as.data.frame.matrix(table(df1[2:1])))
```

Comment: With the first code Iam getting the following error   `> df1<-data.frame(Strings=c("A,B,C,D","A,B,B,D,D,D","A,A,A,A,B,C,D,D"))  
> t(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df1$Strings,','), 1:nrow(df1)))))  
Error in strsplit(df1$Strings, ",") : non-character argument`

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra  I think you have a `factor` column, try `strsplit(as.character(df1$Strings, ','))`

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra  It is to avoid `transposing` the table.  Can you check without using 2:1 and get the table, check how the results needs to be transposed.

Comment: There seems to be one issue with the first code. If there are a large number of observations then after using table the column ind being character is arranged as 1,10,100 and hence the cbind is giving erroneous result

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra  Can you try after converting the column to `numeric` i.e. `transform(stack(...), ind=as.numeric(ind))`

Comment: We need to sort it in ascending after transforming it to numeric. How can we do that?

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra  `df1 <- transform(stack(....), ind= as.numeric(ind)); df2 <- df1[order(df1$ind),]`

Comment: Transform on table is changing its property,transform on stack is not helping

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra  Can you update your post with a new example and the problem you are facing, and expected output.

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra  Updated the first solution.